# 2.8 proportional edit

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

hey guys so i love using the proportional edit when moving vertices around on a project that i have already sub divided. that way everything still keeps , you know.. the proportional shape that i am looking for. I have recently come across a problem in blender 2.8 its not a bug as far as i know.. something in the settings just isnt allowing the prop.editing to do anything ..

I.E: I select one vertex, move it hoping that the surrounding vertices will follow proportionally. what happens though is that no proportional editing takes place what so ever. the only vertex that move is the selected vertex.

I read in a previous post that the mouse wheel adjusts the proportional radius, but mouse wheel is just for zoom in/out as far as i know.

if anyone has a solution i will be for ever grateful.

DB4L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the vertex selected the mouse wheel will work when you are actually moving the vert. Select the vertex, press <kbd>G</kbd> (move), and as you move roll the mouse wheel. Make sure *Proportional Editing* is switched on (shortcut <kbd>O</kbd>).

Alternatively, you can use the <kbd>Page Up ↑</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down ↓</kbd> keys if you don't have a mouse with a wheel.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What if somebody uses a Wacom or Pentablet and don't use a mouse so no mouse Wheel..please improve your answer to get the best possible Information to the quest giver and the people facing the same Problem.

Comment: The *Page Up* and *Page Down* keys have the same function as the mouse wheel (the answer is updated now)